# failed to unmarshall using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

So, I have a JAXBContext

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
```

referring to the documentation,

> if you do newInstance(Foo.class), the newly created JAXBContext} will
>   recognize both  Foo  and  Bar, but not FooBar

```
class Foo {
  @XmlTransient FooBar c;
  Bar b;
}
```

Problem is, when I try to unmarshall XML to Foo, like:

```
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlString);
```

xmlString is a representation of Foo, but the unmarshaller fails to deliver an 
obj instanceof Foo, but instead it delivers a Bar instance.
(I made it simple, the problem arises when context knows 5-6 classes)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any kind of error message, `Exception` or whatsoever?

Comment: no, no Exception, it failes silently

Comment: What is `xmlString`'s value?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to marshal it, and the marshalled XML representation?

Comment: xmlString is the same String generated via the marshalling process in the same context.
`Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            m.marshal(fooObject, out);`

Comment: What is the literal value of the `String`? Not how you create / obtain it, but its content.